# Change the image's origin of map annotation view?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

The regular annotation pin's origin is in the middle of the bottom
so, the pin always point to the same place.

But when I add my custom image, its origin is the center of the image, so every zoom in or out, the bottom of my image point to a different place.

[image]

Here my pin is supposed to point to the center of paris BUT

[image]

but when I zoom in, the bottom of my pin isn't pointing to the center of Paris.

I'm trying with the `CGRect.origin` but didn't get anything useful.

Here is my code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView * customPinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] init];
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"waterPin.png"] ;
    CGRect resizeRect;
    resizeRect.size.height = 40;
    resizeRect.size.width = 40;
    resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
    [img drawInRect:resizeRect];
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    customPinView.image = resizedImage;
    return customPinView;
}
```

Comment: if you could post some code??

Comment: What coordinates (lat/long) is the annotation set to exactly?  Try setting `customPinView.centerOffset` to adjust the image offset (but I'd verify the coordinates first).  Also, you should use initWithAnnotation instead of just init for MKAnnotationView.

Comment: no no, the coordinates is right, but it's that little property, centerOffset, thanks a lot

Comment: hello can you tell me how can we replace the default pin with "waterPin.png" .

Comment: it is in code above, just get your image, and assign it to the image property of the annotation
img = .....;
pin.image = img;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MKAnnotationView` has a `centerOffset` property which you can try setting to adjust the image offset:

```
customPinView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(xOffset,yOffset);
```

Unrelated, but you should use `initWithAnnotation` instead of just `init` for creating an `MKAnnotationView`.
It also wouldn't hurt to use `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` and implement annotation view re-use to improve performance.

I would also suggest not programmatically resizing the image in the delegate method and instead using an already-resized image to begin with.  Then you can just do `customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"resizedWaterPin.png"];` without spending run-time resizing the annotation images every time.

Comment: what about the dragging?!
I set it draggable = YES, but not all the view, I need to click in some exact places to drag it. I want it to be dragged wherever I touch it

Comment: Make sure your annotation class implements setCoordinate otherwise it can't be dragged even if draggable is YES.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927692/ios-mkmapview-draggable-annotations and [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW22).

Comment: it's dragging, yes I implemented the needed methods, but the pin itself, I need to touch them from specific locations, not any where of the pin

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand.  You might want to start a new question with more details.