# Implementing MKPinAnnotationView drag feature?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, draggable, mkpinannotationview

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial for implementing dragging feature for `MKPinAnnotationView` in iPhone `MKMapView`?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927692/ios-mkmapview-draggable-annotations and many others

Answer (score 4):

you can find source code demo for MKPinAnnotationView Drag & drop feature from [this](http://code4app.net/ios/MapKit-Drag-And-Drop/4f8cc5ff06f6e73e69000000) link.

**Update:** The Github project link given in above site url is not working. But I found new project example for that from [this](https://github.com/nithinkmichael/iOS-MapKitDragAndDrop) url.

Answer (score 3):

To make an annotation draggable, set the annotation view's draggable property to YES.

This is normally done in the viewForAnnotation delegate method so make sure you set the `MKMapView` delegate to `self` and conform to it in the .h file.

For example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString *reuseId = @"pin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pav = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (pav == nil)
    {
        pav = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        pav.draggable = YES; // Right here baby!
        pav.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        pav.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pav;
}
```

Ok, so here is the code to manage a annotations drag action:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
    annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView 
    didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
    fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) // you can check out some more states by looking at the docs
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
    }
}
```

This should help!