# Add gesture recognizer to MKPointAnnotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture

I'm junior in Objective-C. I've a task to add gesture recognizer to MKPointAnnotation.I've heard it's possible to do via MKMapView delegate.But I didn't understand it yet.
    So, I've a map, which is present via MKPointAnnotation and I've one or more geomarks, which are present via MKPointAnnotation.
        How to decide this task?
My code example:

```
MKPointAnnotation *newPinAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D pinCoordinate;
pinCoordinate.latitude = self.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
pinCoordinate.longitude = self.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
newPinAnnotation.coordinate = pinCoordinate;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:newPinAnnotation];
```

Comment: You may find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927692/ios-mkmapview-draggable-annotations) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand completely, which action you would like to implement.
But I think that it will help you.
You should implement one or both of these MKMapViewDelegate methods:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view;

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
```