# Delete annotations from the map

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How could i delete annotations from the map after chosing the new one ? 
So let's say i have chosen pin on the X and Y coordinates and would like to move this pin to another place without adding the new one.
Also simply `map.RemoveAnnotations();` does not work.

Here is a code which depends on it:

```
map = new MKMapView(new CGRect(0, 74 + point * 13, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - (74 + point * 20))));
map.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
map.ZoomEnabled = true;
map.ScrollEnabled = true;
map.MapType = MKMapType.Standard;
map.ShowsUserLocation = true;


var longTap = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer() { };
longTap.AddTarget(() => AddPin(longTap, slider.Value));
longTap.MinimumPressDuration = 2.0;
map.AddGestureRecognizer(longTap);

map.GetViewForAnnotation += (mapView, annotation) =>
{

        anView = new MKAnnotationView(annotation, Resources.kClusterAnnotationId);
        anView.ClipsToBounds = true;
        anView.CanShowCallout = false;
        anView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("Icons/customMapPin.png");


    return anView;
};

private void AddPin(UILongPressGestureRecognizer longTap, float value)
{
    if (ifPointExist == false)
    {
        ifPointExist = true;
        touchPoint = longTap.LocationInView(map);
        pinMapCords = this.map.ConvertPoint(touchPoint, map);
        CLLocation loc = new CLLocation(pinMapCords.Latitude, pinMapCords.Longitude);
        map.AddAnnotations(new MKPointAnnotation()
        {
            Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(pinMapCords.Latitude, pinMapCords.Longitude)
        });
        CLGeocoder geocoder = new CLGeocoder();
        geocoder.ReverseGeocodeLocation(loc, (CLPlacemark[] placemarks, NSError error) =>
        {
            str = placemarks[0].AddressDictionary;
            str.ToString();
        });
        AddCircle(value);
        MKCoordinateSpan span = new MKCoordinateSpan(0.10, 0.10);
        var coords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(pinMapCords.Latitude, pinMapCords.Longitude);
        map.Region = new MKCoordinateRegion(coords, span);
        ifPointExist = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think `MapKit` markers can be dragged by users. Try using Google Maps.

Comment: What abaout deleting them and adding new once ?

Comment: As a user, I don't think it's very user-friendly. Imagine trying to drag a marker but the marker does not change postion until you release your finger.

Comment: It might not be, but i have to do this somehow using this one ;/

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927692/ios-mkmapview-draggable-annotations

Comment: This is in Object C which i do not know.