# iOS mkmap - animating annotation on map jumps while zoom in/out

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview, caanimation

An annotation moving on map, and trying to zoom or scroll the map an annotation jump to original position from where it has stared animation.

I am adding animation to the layer of annotation after adding to the mkmapview.

Thanks in advance. This is my first question on stack overflow.

Comment: Please share the minimum amount of code needed to recreate the issue

Comment: [annotationObj.layer addAnimation:caAnimationobj]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927692/ios-mkmapview-draggable-annotations
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998765/how-to-manage-drag-and-drop-for-mkannotationview-on-ios
you may have your solution here .

Comment: if your animation is actually changing the location of the pin then @MartinJacob comment above will help you as you will need to reset the pin location to the new animated location otherwise the map will continue to place the pin back to its original locaiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer actually it can not be achieved by adding an animcation to annotation. I have found out the [Interpolate function](https://github.com/RemiKoutcherawy/OriSim3D-IOS/blob/master/Classes/Interpolator.m) through which I can get the locations between "From" and "To" lat/lng and set it to the annotation(setting annotation location in milliseconds) will look like an animation.