# iOS Mapkit Annotation is not getting draggable

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I am new to iOS development and I need to implement a draggable annotation in iOS maps. my code is given below.whater ever I do I can't get a draggable annotation can anyone help with the annotations  after that  I need  to get address of the location where the pin is pointing

**RegistrationViewController.swift**

```
class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,MKMapViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var centerLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.964370125970357, 77.59643554937497)
        var mapspan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        var mapregion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerLocation, mapspan)
        self.mapView.setRegion(mapregion, animated: true)

        let pin = pinAnnotation(title:"hello",subtitle:"how are you",coordinate:centerLocation)
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
        if annotation is MKPointAnnotation {
            let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")
            pinAnnotationView.pinColor = .purple
            pinAnnotationView.isDraggable = true
            pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
            pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

            return pinAnnotationView
        }

        return nil
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
        switch newState {
        case .starting:
            view.dragState = .dragging
        case .ending, .canceling:
            view.dragState = .none
        default: break
        }
    }
```

**pinAnnotation.swift**

```
import MapKit

class pinAnnotation:NSObject,MKAnnotation {
    var title:String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    init(title:String,subtitle:String,coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case `annotation` is not an `MKPointAnnotation` type. Thats why its not entering into `if annotation is MKPointAnnotation {` condition.

It should be like:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is pinAnnotation {

        let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")
        pinAnnotationView.pinTintColor = .purple
        pinAnnotationView.isDraggable = true
        pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
        pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

        return pinAnnotationView
    }

    return nil
}
```

Because `annotation` is `pinAnnotation` type.

And I can not see `mapView.delegate  = self` in your code. But if you assign it via storyboard thats fine otherwise add it in `viewDidLoad` method.

And your complete code will be:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate  = self
        let centerLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.964370125970357, longitude: 77.59643554937497)
        let mapspan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let mapregion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerLocation, mapspan)
        self.mapView.setRegion(mapregion, animated: true)

        let pin = pinAnnotation(title:"hello",subtitle:"how are you",coordinate:centerLocation)
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin)

    }


    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is pinAnnotation {

            let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")
            pinAnnotationView.pinTintColor = .purple
            pinAnnotationView.isDraggable = true
            pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
            pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

            return pinAnnotationView
        }

        return nil
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
        switch newState {
        case .starting:
            view.dragState = .dragging
        case .ending, .canceling:
            view.dragState = .none
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can get new location with `view.annotation?.coordinate`

check below code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChange newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
    switch newState {
    case .starting:
        view.dragState = .dragging
    case .ending, .canceling:
        //New cordinates
        print(view.annotation?.coordinate)
        view.dragState = .none
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: bro can you tell me how to get the location address to which the marker is pointing now

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Comment: Thanks bro, you made my day

Comment: Updating `view.dragState = .dragging` helped me in my case to update the custom pin location, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have the first step done by setting the `isDraggable` property to true.
Now you only need to handle when the user stops dragging and drops the annotation, see:
[how to manage drag and drop for MKAnnotationView on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998765/how-to-manage-drag-and-drop-for-mkannotationview-on-ios)

Besides, your pinAnnotation should have a settable coordinates.

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html):

> Marking Your Annotation View as Draggable Annotation views provide
>   built-in dragging support, which makes it very easy to drag
>   annotations around the map and to ensure that the annotation data is
>   updated accordingly. To implement minimal support for dragging:
>
> In your annotation objects, implement the setCoordinate: method to
>   allow the map view to update the annotation’s coordinate point. When
>   creating your annotation view, set its draggable property to YES. When
>   the user touches and holds a draggable annotation view, the map view
>   begins a drag operation for it. As the drag operation progresses, the
>   map view calls the
>   mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState: method of its
>   delegate to notify it of changes to the drag state of your view. You
>   can use this method to affect or respond to the drag operation.
>
> To animate your view during a drag operation, implement a custom
>   dragState method in your annotation view. As the map view processes
>   drag-related touch events, it updates the dragState property of the
>   affected annotation view. Implementing a custom dragState method gives
>   you a chance to intercept these changes and perform additional
>   actions, such as animating the appearance of your view. For example,
>   the MKPinAnnotationView class raises the pin off the map when a drag
>   operation starts and drops the pin back down on the map when it ends.

You are missing the `mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState:` method